# I have a 1300 line excel spreadsheet that needs to get into a wordpress site ASAP - Looking for ideas

Tags: database, google-docs

I have an excel spreadsheet that needs to get on a WP site PDQ and IE is choking on it.

I tried making an html table, but it's huge.

I looked into some kind a database plugin that would let me import a cvs and then let users browse it, but I can't even figure out the right search terms.

I would appreciate any input. Thanks.

My question: Do you have any suggestions?

---

#### update 1/15/2011

I ended up using these steps -

1. Go to **Google Docs**
2. open the spreadsheet
3. click **Share**
4. **Publish as a web page**
5. select the sheet to publish
6. click Start publishing
7. click on All cells field
8. insert the cells range, e.g. A2:A3
9. click **Republish now**
10. copy *the-link*
11. **Close**.

Example -

```
<iframe src="The-Link" width="w" height="h" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

- `the-link` = url from google
- `w` = width in pixels
- `h`  = height in pixels

Comment: @user2469 - Can you show us a small subset example so we can understand what you are trying to do? What type of data does the spreadsheet contain? How about showing up 10 rows of the table?

Comment: please move your solution into answer so it's more clear as such and in line with site's mechanics  (yep, you can answer your own questions and accept answer after some waiting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Google Docs, then this plugin [Google Spreadsheet Viewer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/inline-google-spreadsheet-viewer/) might be helpful.

Comment: It turns out that there is a great way to present data that you don't want to share for copying.

You can setup a private Google Doc and use an iframe to display it and people can't go into the source to copy your data. I put a simple no right click script in and some no print css code and the average Joe is not getting this data.

One of you guys might get it, but most folks have no chance. :)

Answer (score 6):

Do you need this data properly integrated in WordPress or merely available for users to view?

If latter I'd not bother with import and just used something more fitting like [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/) to put spreadsheet online and [embed](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55244) at site (there is probably bunch of plugins for this as well).

Comment: This thing was making me crazy. I finally decided to with Google Docs (thanks Rarst) and use a simple iframe..

Answer (score 1):

1300 rows is a LOT for a user to browse through. However, if you do want it as a table in a WP page use the WP Table Reloaded plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-table-reloaded/). You can set the resulting table to paginate, be searchable and be sortable. If you want more spreadsheet functionality than that I'd either post it at Google Docs or Zoho or provide the Excel file as a download that people can manipulate offline.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the data in the excel as an HTML table, you may need to add extra table in the WP database and export the data in the excel file there. Then pull the content of that table, paginate it and return it as a shortcode, so you could easily put it in a post or even inside a custom template.

Jeff Star at Preshible Press has written something like that. And though, he used preexisting table; creating a new table and following the rest of the tutorial is not that painful. Here is the link: http://perishablepress.com/press/2010/11/04/importing-wordpress-users-via-csv-files/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

#### update 1/15/2011

I ended up using these steps -

1. Go to **Google Docs**
2. open the spreadsheet
3. click **Share**
4. **Publish as a web page**
5. select the sheet to publish
6. click Start publishing
7. click on All cells field
8. insert the cells range, e.g. A2:A3
9. click **Republish now**
10. copy *the-link*
11. **Close**.

Example -

```
<iframe src="The-Link" width="w" height="h" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

- `the-link` = url from google
- `w` = width in pixels
- `h`  = height in pixels